# ActiveRecord :dependent => :delete with wrong id attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Step` class that can be an origin, a step or a destination depending on the `model`. And a `Route` class that contains a origin and destination like bellow :

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :origin, -> {where(model: "origin")}, class_name: "Step", :foreign_key => "origin_id", :dependent => :delete
  has_one :destination, -> {where(model: "destination")}, class_name: "Step", :foreign_key => "destination_id", :dependent => :delete
```

I want to delete the linked steps when I destroy a route, but I got this error : `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: steps.origin_id`

How Can I explain to AR that it must find `steps.id` and not `steps.origin_id` ?

Here is my schema.

```
create_table "steps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "model"
    t.float    "lat"
    t.float    "lng"
    t.text     "formatted_address"
    t.string   "vicinity"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "distance"
    t.integer  "duration"
    t.integer  "tour_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end

  add_index "steps", ["tour_id"], name: "index_steps_on_tour_id"

  create_table "routes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "origin_id"
    t.integer  "destination_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "routes", ["user_id"], name: "index_routes_on_user_id"
```

Comment: Aren't you specifying the foreign key yourself here: `:foreign_key => "origin_id"`? If there is no foreign key in `steps` table, then I suppose you have `step_id` in your `routes` table?

Comment: On which table are the `origin_id` and `destination_id` defined? If it is the `routes` table then you have the associations in the opposite way and you should use `belongs_to` instead of `has_one`.

Comment: show your schema please.

Comment: @BoraMa, it was because the `has_one` should be `belongs_to`.

Comment: @Alain, great, I made an answer from this, if you'd like to close this issue. I added some more context to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the associations defined in the opposite way.

Under Rails, the convention is the following: the model *the table of which contains the foreign key*, uses `belongs_to` for the associations. The other models, which have no foreign keys on their tables, use `has_one`, `has_many` etc. for associations.

So in this case, the associations in `Route` should look like the following:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin, -> {where(model: "origin")}, class_name: "Step", :foreign_key => "origin_id", :dependent => :delete
  belongs_to :destination, -> {where(model: "destination")}, class_name: "Step", :foreign_key => "destination_id", :dependent => :delete
end
```

See [this chapter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) in the Rails guides for more info.